# 'str' object has no attribute 'text'| BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When running the following code I get an error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseURL= 'https://www.olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/sprzedaz/pomorskie/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0'}

offer_links = []

for x in range (1,2):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/sprzedaz/pomorskie/?page={x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    offer_list= soup.find_all('div', class_='space rel')
    for item in offer_list:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            offer_links.append(link['href'])

print(offer_links)

for link in offer_links:
    r= requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    nazwa = soup.find('h1',class_='css-1oarkq2-Text eu5v0x0').text.strip()
    szczegoly = soup.find('p',class_='css-xl6fe0-Text eu5v0x0').text.strip()
    cenazam2=[]
    poziom=[]
    umeblowane=[]
    rynek=[]
    zabudowa=[]
    powi=[]
    for i in range(0,7):
        p=szczegoly[i].text.strip()
        if("Cena" in p): 
            cenazam2.append(p)
        elif("Poziom" in p or "SSD" in p):
            poziom.append(p)
        elif("Umeblowane" in p):
            umeblowane.append(p)
        elif("Rynek" in p):
            rynek.append(p)
        elif("zabudowy" in p):
            zabudowa.append(p)
        elif("Powierzchnia" in p):
            powi.append(p)   
    oferty = {'Nazwa':nazwa,'Cena':cenazam2,'Poziom':poziom,'Umeblowane':umeblowane,'Rynek':rynek,'Zabudowa':zabudowa,'Powierzchnia':powi}

dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(oferty, orient='index')
dataset = dataset.transpose()
dataset
```

I need something like an attachment. It's for one test link. It works for one link but I would like to automate it to paste data for the selected number of links.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`szczegoly` is a list of string. You assign it here:

```py
szczegoly = soup.find('p',class_='css-xl6fe0-Text eu5v0x0').text.strip()
```

So you can no longer access the `PageElements` attributes (`.text`) here:

```py
p=szczegoly[i].text.strip()
```

---

You have to decide where you want to strip the values:

```py
szczegoly = soup.find('p',class_='css-xl6fe0-Text eu5v0x0')
...
p=szczegoly[i].text.strip()
```

or

```py
szczegoly = soup.find('p',class_='css-xl6fe0-Text eu5v0x0').text.strip()
...
p=szczegoly[i]
```

These should work, when the element/index exists.

Comment: New bug after change: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: The element doesn't not exists and is `None`.